# Calling stored procedure from EF 6, do I need the entity added to model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which is not part of my data context.

I am attempting to call it via context.Database.SqlQuery but it is returning no data. However if I run the same query from within SSMS I get the expected data back.

My thinking is maybe I need to add to add the stored procedure to my model?

Secondly, my sproc returns a lot of data, but for testing I have created a small subset class just with one property. It matches one of the columns that the sproc returns. I assume that if the sproc returns columns which are not in my POCO, they will be ignored?

My POCO

```
public class TestExpotLeads
{
    public int LeadID { get; set; } // The stored proc has many more columns, but I am just trying to get one column/property to lineup correctly
}
```

Populating that model:

```
var testResult = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<TestExpotLeads>("[dbo].[sp_ExportLeads] @EventID, @CompanyID",
    new SqlParameter("@EventID", eventId),
    new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", companyId)).ToList();
```

testResult is an empty list, but if I run this via SSMS I get data:

```
exec [dbo].[sp_ExportLeads] @EventID = 1, @CompanyID = 1
```

Edit:
I tried to log the query to see the generated SQL and I got this:

```
[dbo].[sp_ExportLeads]
-- @EventID: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- @CompanyID: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
```

It does not look like valid SQL though, but that might just be how the logging outputs it.

Comment: I've seen some examples that use `exec [dbo]....` instead of just the sp name. Try that. Otherwise, maybe your parameter values are not what you think they are. If you debug at runtime what are the values of `eventId` and `companyId`?

Comment: @Crowcoder they are as expected. I did try logging the query and I didn't get exactly what was executed

Comment: So did you try including `exec` in the `SqlQuery<>`?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, but still no change, list is still empty

Comment: by the way, this is not your problem but the prefix `sp_` should be reserved for "special" system procedures. It can cause a slight performance hit.

Comment: If you are familiar with SQL Profiler I would suggest running a trace to see exactly what SQL hits the database and even if you are connecting to the database you think you are.